# Example for creating and rotating of a mathematical function in a script

Tags: scripting, mathematics

I want to make a body by rotating of this function in a script:

## Function

#### X equation

`(ln( ((v*pi)/1)-(pi/2) ) *(1/pi)+3)*sin(u)`

#### Y equation

`(ln( ((v*pi)/1)-(pi/2) )*(1/pi)+3)*cos(u)`

#### Z equation

`v`

Are there any examples how I can do this?

Comment: Please use the [search function first](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/607/30849). You have a parenthesis mismatch. I have not figured out how to use **log** with this addon.

Comment: As it stands, your expressions have mismatched brackets -  (e.g. the right bracket just before +3 in the X equation) - so they are ambiguous ..

Comment: try animation nodes. I already tried it and it works for this type of things.

Comment: @Hen Would you mind writing that into an answer with easy to follow steps how one could create this mathematical surface?

Comment: @Leander I am currently not at my PC but in 3h I could do that.

Comment: Felix, please don't remove the backticks ` of my edit. I have added them back in. Without them your multiplication sign `*` works as a markdown cursive indicator and is not shown.

Comment: what is meant with "by rotating of this function". If it means that you take a uv plane and map it to 3D with that function then my answer will be correct

Answer (score 1):

Your Animation Nodes Node Setup would look like this:

[image: Node Setup]

Basically it takes a generated grid mesh and deforms it with your functions to your 3D object which also gets constructed at the end. I used Math Nodes everywhere, but if you find out how you could use expressions or phython scripts to do that. The problem which I faced with expressions was the type being a list. Math Nodes handle that automatically so you dont have to worry about that. The generated Object would look like this:

[image: LogCylinder]

Answer (score 1):

For Python scripting, you might look first at
[Spin mesh (to create solid of revolution)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30976/spin-mesh-to-create-solid-of-revolution)

Then with your formulae, observe the x and y are of the form

x = r * sin,  y = r * cos

with r as function of v --- r(v) = (ln( ((v*pi)/1)-(pi/2) ) *(1/pi)+3)

So build a 'mesh' of single joined lines, say in the y, z plane.

To get the vertices (0,y,z), pick a series of z values and find the y's

y = r(v) same here as y = r(z).

Then use spin() to get your body of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

## Add an XYZ Math Surface

With the addon *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* enabled, you can add with `Add` > `Mesh` > `Math Function` > `XYZ Math Surface` lots of different mathematical surfaces.[image: how to add]

You will see a lot of options for this operator also `x`, `y` and `z`. But just pasting the terms you stated in your question doesn't work:[image: error]
There is an error because there are **3 things wrong with you python code**:

1. The python function for the natural logarithm $\ln$ in Blender is `log()`, not `ln()`
2. As @Leander pointed out **there is a paranthesis mismatch**. In this explanation I will just assume that closure of the first "(" is on the very end of each term.
3. $\ln(x)$ is **not defined** for values of $x<0$. Your code without sine/cosine part in maths is
   $\frac{1}{\pi}\ln(\frac{v\pi}{1}-\frac{\pi}{2})) +3$
   or simplyfied
   $\frac{\ln(\pi(v-0.5))}{\pi} +3$.
   Here we easily spot that we have to prevent $v$ from being less or equal than $0.5$, because otherwise the $\ln$ is undefined and an error will be raised. Unfortunately the `V min` value in the options of the *Add XYZ Math Surface* operator cannot be set to a number greater 0 so we have to hack a bit:

The solution is to use a helper function in which `v` is checked if it is greater than `0.5`. If not, the helper function will set the result to 0. In the following image you can see all the options used to plot

[image: result]

Comment: I never knew Math Function exists and I am seeing Mechanical beneath. I will explore them today. Thank you for posting this.